# dojo/parser::parse() error in Worklight v6

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Dojo in Worklight v.6.

When I'm using the preview I get a Dojo parse error in the Chrome console.

```
    dojo/parser::parse() error Error {} core-web-layer.js:56
    (anonymous function) core-web-layer.js:56
    g dojo.js:89
    then.b.then dojo.js:92
    b.extend.otherwise dojo.js:42
    u.parse core-web-layer.js:56
    (anonymous function) dojo.js:34
    c core-web-layer.js:310
    (anonymous function) dojo.js:3
    p dojo.js:2
    n.signal dojo.js:3
    da dojo.js:15
    ga dojo.js:15
    o dojo.js:17
    (anonymous function) dojo.js:19
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add your main HTML and JS files of your worklight app? The chrome console doesn't always show the complete error message btw. I sometimes use different browsers to see if they throw another error.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a new Dojo library

Comment: Indeed, that's why I asked your HTML + JS ;) Usually when there's a parsing error it's due to a library you use as `data-dojo-type` but when you didn't define it in a `require()` statement.

Comment: If your Chrome console shows `error Error {}`, you can close the console and reopen it. The console will then show more details in `{}` that will help troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a new Dojo library

Answer (score 0):

import all library

```
function dojoInit() {
    require([ "dojo", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
...
```